# How to protect specific route in next-auth

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm building a simple client app with react and next-auth. 
I want to protect only one route `/secret` and the rest of routes are all publicly accessible.

The top level of app is wrapped with `SessionProvider`:

```
    import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"
    export default function MyApp({
      Component,
      pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
    }) {
      return (
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </SessionProvider>
      )
    }
```

And I understood I can use `useSession` to check if user is signed in. 
But I wonder how to protect one specific route: `/secret`. If I wrap only `<Secret />` component with `<SessionProvider>`, I won't be able to access session from `Secret` component. Then how can I do that..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NextAuth's middleware, create a `middleware.js` file in your root directory (on previous Next.js versions, you had to create a `_middleware.js` file inside your `pages` folder) and add this:

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware"

export const config = { matcher: ["/your-secured-route"] }
```

If you don't add a `config`, then all routes will be protected by default.

Comment: I tried this, but adding a middleware.ts does not do anything to my app. How come?

Comment: What Next.js and Next auth versions are you using?

Comment: I made it work (directory issue), but actually, just with this code in it, my middleware will make me stuck on the login page, even after successful login. Next is on latest, and next-auth is 4.20.1+